# How to replace element values in the list if element is not None?

Tags: python

I need to remove some specific character from a list of element, but some element is None.

I have a list of elements, such as

```
row= ['Hello,World','$Hello World', None]
```

I need a python code to remove',' and '$'from the element.
My code looks like this but is an invalid syntax:

```
row=[item.replace('$','').replace(',','') if item is not None for item in row]
```

I need to keep the None in the list, so the required output should be `['HelloWorld', 'Hello World', None]`

Please suggest how to fix it, thank you

Comment: That's invalid formation of comprehension. `if`s without `else` should come last.

Comment: you want to keep None?

Comment: `else` is mandatory in [conditional expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions), to provide a value to use when `item is None`. If you were to put the `if` clause at the end of the [comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#displays-for-lists-sets-and-dictionaries), it would instead filter out the `None` elements.

Comment: `item.translate(None, '$,')` can replace the chain of `replace` calls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```py
[item.replace('$', '').replace(',','') for item in row if item]
```

If you want to keep the None

```py
[item.replace('$', '').replace(',','') if item else item for item in row]
```

Note: If you have anything other than strings and Nonetypes in the list, it'd be a good idea to check the element is a string or responds to the replace method before calling replace.

Comment: @Yang L the `if item` at the end will ignore any 'Falsey' item, such as None and empty string.

Comment: This does not include any zeros or `False` in the final output.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `and` operator:

```
[i and i.replace('$','').replace(',','') for i in row]
```

This returns:

```
['HelloWorld', 'Hello World', None]
```